# Problem when I press the button I have an error in the console log which says my function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, function

When you click on the button the Console says:

> project3.html:48 Uncaught ReferenceError: findnembers is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (project3.html:48)

Why is that?

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>project3</title>
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
    <button id="click here to calculate" onclick="findnembers();" type=button>click here to calculate </button>
    <div id='rslt' style='text-align: center;font-size: 1em; font-weight: bolder;' value=""></div>
    <script>
        function sumdigits(num) {
            sum = 0;
            while (num) {
                sum += num % 10;
                num = Math.floor(num / 10);
            }
            return sum;
        }
        function findnembers() {
            var counter = 0;
            var list='<ol>';
            for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
                var ezer = sumdigits(i);
                if (ezer === 9) {
                list+= "<li>" + i + "</li>";
                 counter++;
                }
            list += "</ol>";
            }
            var print=list+
            <p style='text-align: center;font-size: 1em; font-weight: bolder;'>"The  sum of digits of those number is 9, and they are in the range 0 to 9999 inclusive and their quantity is "{counter}</p>;
            document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML=print;
        } 
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: `var print=list+ <p style='text-a` is an obvious syntax error. Fix that first

Comment: You aren't quoting the html string properly

Comment: something like  `var print=`\``${list}<p style='text-a ....`\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @kinglish said quoting . it should be like this

```
 var print=`${list}<p style='text-align: center;font-size: 1em; font-weight: bolder;'>"The  sum of digits of those number is 9, and they are in the range 0 to 9999 inclusive and their quantity is "${counter}</p>`;
```